# PTIJ: Why did the chicken cross the road?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Just wondering if Torah sources have any answer to the world's most timeless and compelling question: why did the chicken cross the road?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Nafka mina: was it a *melacha she'eina tzricha legufaH* ...

Comment: It was a glitch in the matrix. .

Comment: I don't see how this question is [on-topic](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/797).

Comment: @msh210 good point

Comment: @msh210 doesn't it fall under "apply a distinctly Torah style (e.g. Talmudic analysis) to an irrelevant topic"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is one of four riddles that the wisest of all men was unable to solve ([Proverbs 30:18-19](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%9C_%D7%99%D7%97)):

> שְׁלֹשָׁה הֵמָּה נִפְלְאוּ מִמֶּנִּי וארבע [וְאַרְבָּעָה] לֹא יְדַעְתִּים.
> דֶּרֶךְ הַנֶּשֶׁר בַּשָּׁמַיִם דֶּרֶךְ נָחָשׁ עֲלֵי צוּר דֶּרֶךְ אֳנִיָּה בְלֶב יָם וְדֶרֶךְ גֶּבֶר בְּעַלְמָה.‏
>
> Three things are beyond me, and the fourth I don't know:
> Why did the eagle cross the sky?
> Why did the snake cross the rock?
> Why did the ship cross the sea?
> Why did the rooster cross the road with a hen?

Answer (score 9):

The midrash explains that the chicken* is actually **Avraham Avinu**.

As we learn in the commentaries to the Haggadah, Avraham, by choosing Hashem, "stood on *the other side*", i.e. **the other side of the world**, who all bowed to idols. And hence the name *[Ivri](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.14.13?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)* (*Hebrew)*, i.e. "other sider".

### Why did the chicken cross the road? To get to the other side.

---

<sup>* the original formulation, scholars believe, had "dove" (see [this Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.15.9?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Radak_on_Genesis.15.9.6&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) on Bereshit 15:9), and also it wasn't a road, but a river (see the [opening of Maggid](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Magid%2C_In_the_Beginning_Our_Fathers_Were_Idol_Worshipers.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in the Passover Haggadah)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

to get to the Alter Cocker-doodle Doo.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this was a translation error - I think that the original question involved a **rooster** and not a **chicken**. As for the answer, he had a girsa about the end of [Pirkei Avot 2:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.2.5?ven=Mishnah_Yomit_by_Dr._Joshua_Kulp&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that read

> וּבְמָקוֹם שֶׁאֵין גֶּבֶרים, הִשְׁתַּדֵּל לִהְיוֹת גֶּבֶר

instead of

> וּבְמָקוֹם שֶׁאֵין אֲנָשִׁים, הִשְׁתַּדֵּל לִהְיוֹת אִישׁ

which he likely got from the [girsa of Bar Kappara](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.63a.11) as translated by b a in the [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/471853?noredirect=1) below:

> בַּאֲתַר דְּלֵית גְּבַר — תַּמָּן הֱוֵי גְּבַר.

> In a place where there is no rooster, there you should be, O rooster

So it must be, therefore, that there was simply no one on the other side of the road.

Comment: Your conjecture is right on track, this is the girsa of Bar Kappara: באתר דלית גבר תמן הוי גבר "In a place where there is no rooster, there you should be, O rooster" ([Berachot 63a](https://shas.alhatorah.org/Full/Berakhot/63a.11#e0n6))

Answer (score 3):

The question is obviously existential, and therefore you already knew the answer before you asked the question.

As Rav Berg put it so eloquently in his book, [Kabbalah for the Layman](https://www.kabbalah.com/en/articles/illusion-versus-reality/),

> “From the kabbalistic perspective, that which is infinite and eternal is real and that which is finite, including this world and all that is a part of it, is illusion.”

Wisdom calls to us from Proverbs 8:17

> "I love them that love me, And those that seek me earnestly shall find me."

The path is manifest by the intent of the seeker.

The bottom line is: there is no road.

There is only the need in the mind of the creation to seek elevation to the Creator. And toward that need, the road materializes.

Comment: The second bottom line is: There is no chicken either. Anyone can confirm this when hungry.